# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375/. Is the docker daemon running? Gitlab-ci in private repository

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

I have docker-compose file which is working fine locally on my computer. I register gitlab-runner on the same pc and every pipeline where I use any docker command fails with an error: "docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?". I believe I've tried all proposed solutions - nothing works. I use private company network with VPN, maybe it is the issue.
My gitlab-ci.yml

```
build:docker:
  image: docker:19.03.12-dind

  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    DOCKER_PRIVILEGED: "true"
  services: 
    - name: docker:19.03.12-dind
      alias: docker
      command: ["--tls=false"]
  before_script:
    - apk update
    - apk upgrade
    - apk add py3-pip docker
    - apk add --no-cache bash python3
    - docker build -t $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}_server.$CI_PIPELINE_ID ./server/
    - docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
    # - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

my gitlab-runner created as a docker container
using docker exe

If someone faced the same problem please help me understand what am I missing here.

Comment: Can you provide your sanitized gitlab-runner configuration toml?

Comment: @sytech
`concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "crunner"
  url = "https://git.icdc.io/"
  token = "********************"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:3.15.0"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
`

Comment: There's nothing that sticks out to me as misconfigured. As long as `docker` is properly installed/running on the _host_ system and the user/group running the `gitlab-runner` process has permission to access the docker socket, I would expect this configuration to work.

Comment: @sytech I sign in as a root user and in docker there are some running containers already. They seem to run properly.